# Get element by ID does nothing

Tags: javascript, php, css, mysqli

In my PHP document I pull data from, for example, myDatabase. I then proceed to assign a value from a table in my Database to a variable. I know that this variable, which happens to be $fileLoc1, does have a value, for when I put

```
echo $fileLoc1;
```

It returns a value, or in my case a url to a file. Basically, what this does is tell the user if a file is available for download. I have the following code to check this.

```
if ($fileLoc1 === NULL) { 
    echo "<script>
             document.getElementById ('alert-sng-available').style.display 
                   = 'none !important';
          </script>"; 
    echo "<script>
              document.getElementById ('alert-sng-Navailable').style.display 
                   = 'block !important';
          </script>";
}
```

In the code above `#alert-sng-available` is the alert that will show the green available `div` and the `alert-sng-Navailable` (not available) will show the red `div`.

When I first put this into my .php file, I thought nothing of it because it worked. *$fileLoc1* is NOT null, therefore using the original settings of the div, showing the green, hiding the red.  However if I edit the code ever so slightly...

```
if ($fileLoc1 !== NULL) { 
    echo "<script>
              document.getElementById ('alert-sng-available').style.display 
                      = 'none !important';
          </script>"; 
    echo "<script>
              document.getElementById ('alert-sng-Navailable').style.display 
                      = 'block !important';
          </script>";
}
```

Can you guess what happens? Nothing. Absolutely, positively nothing. Below is an image showing results from both attempts. On the second snippet of code the green `div` should go away, being replaced by a red `div`. (yes, I'm using bootstrap, that's why I'm using the *!important*, but it doesn't work with or without it)

[image]

The Next picture will show the  tag in the HTML once I change the if statement from `===` to `!==`

[image: in inspect element]

This is in inspect element, clearing showing php evaluated the !== equation to true, which is correct, but now the javascript doesn't work.

Lets try this again but with the `===` equation. It works! There are no script tags 'cause it evaluated to false as it should.

**I'm at a loss here.**

Yes, the divs are labeled correctly, no bootstrap isn't interfering. ***Because*** if I change the properties of both the `alert-sng` divs using "ctrl + shift + i" it works properly! Also, yes my javascript is at the bottom of the page

#### A gif showing it can work

[image: it can work. But it won't]

Comment: Are there any errors shown in the javascript console?

Comment: Can you try placing your js code into window.onload = function () { //your code } ?

Comment: Try doing `console.log(document.getElementById("alert-sng-available"));` before and after you update the style...that might help you figure out the problem.

Comment: Also, those id's you're targeting are definitely correct?

Comment: Taking out `!important` in your javascript made it work for me. This fiddle has `!important` in the javascript and doesn't work. https://jsfiddle.net/squickers/d8u7jzLz/1/ But when you take it out it works fine.

Comment: @SergChernata tried it, unchanged. I'm trying other peoples ideas, with yours still in place to see if it works

Comment: @DiddleDot I originally didn't have the !important tags. Tried removing them, but had no effect.

Comment: @bobjoe there are seven errors. Five of them I know what they are.

Comment: What are the other two?

Comment: @bobjoe both are Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input BUT they are at the top of the error list

Comment: You have to wait for the DOM to be loaded.

Comment: Why are you going through the PHP-JS-CSS/HTML loop, when you can simply use PHP to determine what markup to print to the page conditionally? For example, you can use `echo $fileLoc1 === NULL ? 'xxx' : 'yyy';`

Comment: @Terry new to php, what does the  `? 'xxx' : 'yyy'` do?

Comment: It is a shorthand for an if/else statement (also known as **tenary operators**), `$fileLoc1 === NULL` is the condition, and `xxx` is printed if the condition is satisfied, and `yyy` is printed if the condition is not. For more info: https://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples

Comment: @Terry inputed this `echo $fileLoc1 === NULL) ? "<script>document.getElementById ('alert-sng-available').style.display = 'none';</script>" : "<script>document.getElementById ('alert-sng-Navailable').style.display = 'block'; </script>";` just to see what would happen. evaluated to true.

Comment: You're completely missing the point. You shouldn't even need to use JS at all. Just print the appropriate HTML code in place of `xxx` or `yyy`, e.g. `echo $fileLoc1 === NULL ? '<p>File not available</p>' : '<p>File available</p>';` The thing is, **you do not need to rely on JS to show/hide elements at all**.

Comment: @Terry that makes a little more sense to me :) I'll try it

Comment: @Terry you are a genius. It works! Turn it into an answer and I'll mark it as right

Comment: Should be: "You're in luck!"

Comment: @ehcanadian how did I miss that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the PHP–JS–HTML/CSS pipeline. In fact, you can simply rely on PHP itself to dictate what is shown/hidden on the page itself.

As you have not provided any markup in your code, I will be using a hypothetical example. Let's say you want to print `<p>File available</p>` when the `$fileLoc1` variable is not null, and `<p>File not available</p>` otherwise, we can do this:

```
<?php
if ($fileLoc1 === NULL) {
    echo '<p>File available</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p>File not available</p>';
}
?>
```

For a more concise example, you can also use the [**ternary operators**](https://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples) (`?:`), i.e.:

```
<?php
echo $fileLoc1 === NULL ? '<p>File available</p>' : '<p>File not available</p>';
?>
```

---

If you want both markups to be present so that you can manipulate them using JS later, you can even print both, and dictate the styles conditionally:

```
<p style="<?php echo $fileLoc1 === NULL ? 'display: none': 'display: block'; ?>">File available</p>
<p style="<?php echo $fileLoc1 === NULL ? 'display: block': 'display: none'; ?>">File not available</p>
```

In the case when `$fileLoc` is `NULL`, you will get the following markup:

```
<p style="display: none">File available</p>
<p style="display: block">File not available</p>
```